# Bosun - Get IP address of host using .GetMeta

Tags: go, bosun, scollector

I am trying to create a (golang) struct for handling bosun alerts sent over http. It holds alert details, most importantly, about the `eth0` IP address of the corresponding host.

```
/* This struct is defined as per the notification defined in bosun config */
type BosunAlert struct {
    AckUrl       string   `json:"ack"`
    AlertName    string   `json:"alert_name"`
    LastStatus   string   `json:"last_status"`
    IpMac        []string `json:"ip,omitempty"`
}
```

The corresponding template looks as follows:

```
template template.bosun_listener {
    subject = `{
        "ack":"{{.Ack}}",
        "alert_name":"{{.Alert.Name}}",
        "last_status":"{{.Last.Status}}",
        "ip":{{ .GetMeta "" "addresses" (printf "host=%s,iface=eth0" .Group.host) }}
    }`
    body = ``
}
```

However, I get this error:

```
info: check.go:305: alert.network{host=147210308125790,ifName=server-1609}:
template: template.bosun_listener:6:12: executing "template.bosun_listener" at 
<.GetMeta>: error calling GetMeta: redigo: nil returned
```

I am using a []string for IpMac field as I cannot isolate the eth0 IP from  it's ethernet address.

Any way to do this?

EDIT:
This is the output I get:

```
"ack":"http://localhost:8070/action?
key=alert.network%7Bhost%3D147210308125790%2CifName%3server-1609%7D&type=ack",
"alert_name":"alert.network", "last_status":"critical", "ip":
["172.31.40.31/20","fe80::61:adff:feb1:1f5b/64"] }
```

This is the alert I have configured:

```
alert alert.network {
    runEvery = 5
    $ip = ""
    template = template.bosun_listener
    $usage = avg(q("avg:rate:container.net.bytes{host=*,ifName=server*}", "5m", ""))
    crit = $usage > 100
    critNotification = notification.test
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure that the host in question as an eth0 device (and bosun has indexed that metadata)? nil means it couldn't find the entry.

The following works for me:

```
template test {
    subject = {{ .GetMeta "" "addresses" (printf "host=%s,iface=eth0" .Group.host) }}
}
```

Comment: It does have eth0, I have checked that. The snippet you posted works too. But when I try to use it as I do, it fails. Any pointers why.

Comment: What Bosun version?

Comment: ./bosun --version
bosun version 0.5.0-dev (00772aee8c27482893f885bbdbb10e26f75d7fd0) built 2016-06-22T00:47:49Z

Comment: Not sure ... What you provided would error for me because of `Group` and not `.Group`. Is the snippet different from what you are running. Maybe yo ucan post more/ I'm not sure I understand how the Go struct fits in, is that something you are using in a different process?

Comment: I also don't understand where the `ifName` in the error comes from since the alert that goes with the template is not shown.

Comment: I updated the question. Had missed the '.' while formatting the question here.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122768/discussion-between-krish7919-and-kyle-brandt).

Comment: Might also see if host api sees it: `curl bosun/api/host | jq '."ny-bosun01" | ."Interfaces"'` , replacing ny-bosun01 with your host 147210308125790 ( odd hostname by the way :P )

Comment: Thanks, Kyle.
The hostname is a timestamp. :)
The problem seems to be translating the [IP, Mac] to the golang json struct. I think the bug is on that side. Is there a way to just extract the IP from the host?

Comment: the ifName comes from because I measure the container.net.bytes of an interface. Will edit the question and post the alert.

Comment: alright, I could reproduce this issue and know the root cause. basically when I restart bosun container, scollector does not populate the metadata for a node again. I have opened another one here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39362190/scollector-send-metadata-for-a-node-if-bosun-restarts