# scollector - send metadata for a node if bosun restarts

Tags: monitoring, bosun, scollector

Alerts defined in bosun failed as the metadata was not populated when bosun restarts.

Is there a way to configure scollector to send metadata once the connection to bosun breaks?

I always need to restart bosun as I keep modifying the configuration file.

Comment: Why the downvote? scollector adds the metadata at random times, I want to force it to get metadata in some periodic interval.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bosun stores metadata (and incident info) in redis/ledis. This information is expected to be persisted and not destroyed when Bosun is restarted. There will be a gap in Bosun's ability to receive metadata during this restart though. It doesn't look like the metadata has any retry logic - so not sure if this is what you mean?

Also 0.6.0-beta (due towards the end of Sept 2016) will have config reloading, so restarts are not required when rules etc are edited. You could start using this feature now if you want to run off of master.

Comment: Some retrying would be nice for metadata regardless, I made an issue for it, but not a high prority for us https://github.com/bosun-monitor/bosun/issues/1899 right now.

Comment: Thank you. That will do. Will wait for the 0.6.0 beta. :)